# Change CSS when Scroll down using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

How can I achieve this using PHP: Change the css of a DIV when scrolling down <100px and change it back when >100px.

This is what I would do in normal Javascript but it does not work with PHP

```
<script language='javascript'>
  var fixed = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
if( $(this).scrollTop() >= 100 ) {
    if( !fixed ) {
        fixed = true;
        $('#myDivTop').css({position:'fixed',top:0});
    }
} else {
    if( fixed ) {
        fixed = false;
        $('#myDivTop').css({position:'static'});
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Firstly, learn how PHP works and how JS works. Then you'll find your question funny.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense at all. Why don't you tell us what EXACTLY you want to do? This seems an x-y problem, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't archive the same functionality in PHP, as it can't react to DOM events or update the page (It can give data, but PHP isn't doing the updating). You can use AJAX to call PHP on the page without reloading and it can give data that you can use.

***But*** you can have PHP generate that code and `echo` it out as HTML if that's what you are looking for, your code does not seem to need anything from the server:

```
<?php
echo <<<HERE
<script language='javascript'>
  var fixed = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
if( $(this).scrollTop() >= 100 ) {
    if( !fixed ) {
        fixed = true;
        $('#myDivTop').css({position:'fixed',top:0});
    }
} else {
    if( fixed ) {
        fixed = false;
        $('#myDivTop').css({position:'static'});
    }
}
});
</script>
HERE;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running a JavaScript server side environment (such as Node.js), your JavaScript code will be being executed on the client side (which is why you can manipulate the DOM as you are doing in your code snippet), whereas PHP is being executed on the server side, allowing you to interact with data stored on the server.

It sounds to me like you need to call some server side functionality from JavaScript, and then handle the result of this from JavaScript. In this case, an AJAX call is what you're looking for.

Try [W3Schools AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) for more information on how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can only interact with HTML elements. If you want to achieve this just add your code in in the HTML code... No need to touch php.

Something you can actually do is to write from php to your javascript, like this:

```
<script language='javascript'>
     alert("<?php echo 'Hola amigos'; ?>");

</script>
```