# Add/remove classes on scroll (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to cause a widget to have one class added and one class removed when a user scrolls down the page by 50px and reverse the process when the user scrolls up again.

**Website:** [Link here](http://cluster4.website-staging.uk/simplyfloors.co.uk/)

**Platform:** Wordpress

**Theme:** Customizr-child

My widget that I'm trying to influence has the `header-widget` class applied to it. [This forum thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558311/add-remove-class-with-jquery-based-on-vertical-scroll?noredirect=1) led me to create:

```
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $(".header-widget");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            $(".header-widget").removeClass("header-widget-tallheader");
            $(".header-widget").addClass("header-widget-shortheader");

        } else {
            $(".header-widget").removeClass("header-widget-shortheader");
            $(".header-widget").addClass("header-widget-tallheader");
        }
    });
});
```

As the use of script tags in Wordpress is prohibited as standard [1], I opted to install the 'Scripts n Styles' plugin, which apparently overrides that restriction. I have then inserted the above code such that it appears in `head` tag.

Unfortunately however, nothing is happening. Is this that the script tags still aren't processing? Is my coding wrong? Or should I be using AJAX [2]? If the latter, I read through the W3Schools AJAX tutorial [3] but wasn't sure how to apply it under this circumstance.

Thanks in advance if anyone is able to help. I've spent hours and hours looking into this but still appear to be a beginner, so if any answers could be as descriptive as possible please, I'd be grateful.

**Footnote:**

Due to forum reputation restriction, links I was going to include but can't:

[1] `https://www.godaddy.com/garage/webpro/wordpress/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/`

[2] `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356137/change-css-when-scroll-down-using-php`

[3] `http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, just add `$ = jQuery;` before that.

**CORRECTED CODE**

```
$ = jQuery;
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $(".header-widget");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            $(".header-widget").removeClass("header-widget-tallheader");
            $(".header-widget").addClass("header-widget-shortheader");

        } else {
            $(".header-widget").removeClass("header-widget-shortheader");
            $(".header-widget").addClass("header-widget-tallheader");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked - thank you. Sometimes the answers to the most irritating problems can be simple ones!

Comment: Ha Ha. You're welcome :) . Don't forget one thing, if you think your javascript code is correct and not working, check `console log` to see the error of the javascript. You can search google with those error. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your script to:

```
jQuery(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = jQuery(".header-widget");
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            jQuery(".header-widget").removeClass("header-widget-tallheader");
            jQuery(".header-widget").addClass("header-widget-shortheader");

        } else {
            jQuery(".header-widget").removeClass("header-widget-shortheader");
            jQuery(".header-widget").addClass("header-widget-tallheader");
        }
    });
});
```

The version of jQuery shipped with wordpress doesn´t recognize $

Answer (score 1):

Following code is perfectly works for me:
Here .page_header is header class of my theme.

```
    <script>
jQuery(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = jQuery(".page_header");
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll > 0) {
            jQuery(".page_header").removeClass("header-widget-tallheader");
            jQuery(".page_header").addClass("header-widget-shortheader");

        } else {
            jQuery(".page_header").removeClass("header-widget-shortheader");
            jQuery(".page_header").addClass("header-widget-tallheader");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```